# LibGDX and ObjLoader not displaying .mtl?

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, wavefront

I am trying to load .obj files into an Android project with LibGDX. The files have *no* texture file, but include materials in .mtl files. I'm using the latest official nightly, and rendering the object file only results in the object appearing white. How do I get the ObjLoader to use the .mtl file?

```
@Override
public void create() {
    objLoader = new ObjLoader();
    model = objLoader.loadObj( Gdx.files.internal("data/obj.obj"), true);
}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();

    model.render();

    batch.end();
}
```

This is how the code to render the object is called.
Here is a link to the ObjLoader class

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/loaders/wavefront/ObjLoader.java

What am I doing wrong? And why won't it load the .mtl file? From what I can understand, it should load a .mtl file that's in the same folder and same name as the .obj file.

**EDIT**
I have messed around a bit, putting some lines into the ObjLoader class to log what it is and isn't loading. It looks like it's loading the mtl file, and assigning each mtl to a Material instance, and it also looks like the obj is correctly asking for those materials.

Is there something I need to enable or otherwise do on the OpenGL end to make sure it's using these materials properly?

Answer (score 1):

The ObjLoader and especially the MtlLoader it uses is very limited. Try using the new 3D api with fbx instead. Here's explained how to load a model: http://blog.xoppa.com/loading-models-using-libgdx/.

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged (links tend to get stale over time).
Please consider editing your answer and adding a synopsis here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the very same issue, and that's exactly why I both reported it here:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/2441

and committed a fix to it here:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commit/d7e716351d26ddfba19ce9e0b3bdfb449dbc81b7

, supporting virtually all MTL parameters out there. Note that this is a WIP, and (hopefully) will get into trunk once it's finished.